# can't update and commit a subdirectory with git

Tags: git

I have a subdirectory named explore_california that I thought I added but never successfully commited now I have a message 
"modified: explore_california (untracked content)"
the following screenshot shows what's happening.

http://www.jimslounge.com/problems/no_commit.png

Answer (score 0):

> no changes to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")

You haven’t added the files you want to commit to the index / the staging area yet. As such, there is nothing to commit.

You can add files using `git add <filename>`.

I’d suggest you to read about the [Git basics in the Git book](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Basics).

Comment: I did git add but now I have "non-monotonic index' errors and from what I've read that indicates a corrupt registry so I'm going to delete the .git directory and start over -  thanks

Comment: You could also try just deleting the index file (`.git/index`) if that’s broken. That way, you don’t lose any history from the repository.